# Matrix product demonstration

Tags: soft-question, matrix-calculus, cross-product

Sorry for boring you my friends. I have haunted by a problem of relation between matrix product and cross product.

I would like to demonstrate the following equation:
$$ (\Omega\cdot r)^T(\Omega\cdot r)=\omega^T\cdot I \cdot \omega$$
with:
$$\Omega= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{3}}&\omega_{{2}}
\\ \omega_{{3}}&0&-\omega_{{1}}\\ 
-\omega_{{2}}&\omega_{{1}}&0\end {array} \right] ,
$$

$$I= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {y}^{2}+{z}^{2}&-xy&-xz
\\ -xy&{x}^{2}+{z}^{2}&-yz\\ -xz&-
yz&{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}\end {array} \right] ,
$$
$$r= \left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\ y\\ 
z\end {array} \right] ,
$$
and
$$ \omega = \left[ \begin {array}{c} \omega_{{1}}\\ \omega_{{2}
}\\ \omega_{{3}}\end {array} \right] 
$$
Actually, I could demonstrate this relation in a ugly way that I developed the left side of equation and re-assembled in the form of right side. Meanwhile, I found out there is a relation between the matrix product and the cross product as:
$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{3}}&\omega_{{2}}
\\ \omega_{{3}}&0&-\omega_{{1}}\\ 
-\omega_{{2}}&\omega_{{1}}&0\end {array} \right]\cdot\left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\ y\\ 
z\end {array} \right] = \left[ \begin {array}{c} \omega_{{1}}\\ \omega_{{2}
}\\ \omega_{{3}}\end {array} \right]  \wedge \left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\ y\\ 
z\end {array} \right]$$, thus the left side of the equation could take the form of:
$$(\omega\wedge r)^T(\omega\wedge r)$$
It looks a little more similar to the right side. Eventually, I failed to demonstrate it in a pretty way.

Thank you in advance for taking a look. Have a nice holiday.

Comment: Excuse me, is your question then regarding the aesthetics or the elegance of the derivation?

Comment: Probably yes. I'm very curious and wonder if there is a 'pretty' way, noticing the symmetry of the matrix I and the relation between matrix product and cross product. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is any "prettier" than what you have derived, but you could use the the [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Vector_cross_product) to expand the cross products.

The LHS becomes
$$\eqalign{
 (w\times r)^T(w\times r) &= (wr^T:\epsilon)\cdot(\epsilon:wr^T) \cr
   &= wr^T:(\epsilon\cdot\epsilon):wr^T \cr
   &= wr^T : (\alpha-\beta) : wr^T \cr
   &= wr^T : wr^T - wr^T : rw^T \cr
   &= w^2r^2 - (r^Tw)^2 \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the Frobenius (or double-dot) product, and $(\alpha, \beta)$ are isotropic 4th order tensors with certain ("epsilon-delta") properties
$$\eqalign{
\alpha : M &= M \cr
\beta : M &= M^T \cr
}$$

Note that the moment of inertia tensor can be written as
$$\eqalign{
 I &= r^2E-rr^T \cr
}$$
where E is the identity tensor.

Now the RHS can be written as
$$\eqalign{
 I:ww^T &= (r^2E-rr^T):ww^T \cr
  &= w^2r^2 - (r^Tw)^2 \cr
}$$
which is identical to the LHS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your demonstration is much more beautiful. It helps me a lot.